# Reconocer etiquetas HTML en Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

quiero saber cómo resolver el siguiente problema:

Recibo de una función un string, al cual a su vez se agregan otros dos strings más los cuáles son etiquetas :

```
var completeText = '';

function myFun (str) {

completeText = '<span class="myClass">' + str + '</span>';

return completeText;

}
```

El problema es que al recibir el completeText dentro de la vista, recibo:

> <span class="myClass">[Acá va el texto]</span>

y no el texto que necesito alrededor de las etiquetas, con su estilo.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Para crear etiquetas mediante JavaScript te serviría utilizar **[innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)**, el cual te sirve para crear | adjuntar elementos dentro de un tag padre

```js
let completedText = ''

const build = str => {
  completedText = `<span class="myClass">${str}</span>`
  document.querySelector('#div1').innerHTML = completedText
}
build('palabra')
```

```css
.myClass {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<div id="div1"></div>
```

Nos comentas!

Comment: Gracias! corregí lo de los slash raros, se me fueron. Intenté el temlate string pero no hubo caso, sigo viendo en la vista las etiquetas.

Comment: Que raro :( Edite la respuesta y adjunte un ejemplo.

Comment: Quizás no se entienda la pregunta ahora que la releo. La idea es que la vista reconozca las etiquetas como etiquetas, y no como texto o string. En ese caso, solo debería devolver  'palabra de prueba' y que el navegador identifique ese string de etiquetas, como tales.

Comment: Ahhhh claro! La entendí mal @JoseManuelBorras. Editada :)

Comment: Gracias, funciona, pero no en mi código je. Tengo que aplicarlo a un controlador de Angular.js, pensé que por ahí podía funcionar así tal cual, pero no me reconoce el querySelector

Comment: AngularJS o Angular 2+?

Comment: Es solo AngularJS

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128714/discussion-between-paulo-urbano-rivera-and-jose-manuel-borras).